# Как поделить список на N-списков по длине строк

Tags: c#, list, split

Есть список в котором `n`-строк. Как поделить его на подсписки где суммарная длина символов <=40.

Допустим есть слова,

```
абажур ткань потолок
абажур ткань с
абажур торшер вышивка
абстрактные вышивка
абстрактные вышивки
```

В итоге должно получиться следующее

```
[абажур ткань потолок
абажур ткань с]

[абажур торшер вышивка]

[абстрактные вышивка
абстрактные вышивки]
```

Нашел в сети код, который делит строку на части, только не совсем понятно как его применить ко списку

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength) {
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength) {
        yield return str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index));
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется мне, что ваш метод делит не по к-ву слов, а по к-ву байт. Так вам надо что б в байты влезть, или в слова?

Comment: по количеству символов, пардон

Comment: Похоже к списку он не применим, прийдётся всёравно делать `SplitByLength(Myarray.join(" "),40)`. Либо самому написать. Можно какапливать с предпроверкой на длинну буфер, и при детекте переполнения сбрасывать и обнулять буфер.

Comment: а если все строки будет по 30 символов?  нужно ли разбивать строку? или в группе будет просто одна строка 30 символов?

Comment: Если строка будет по 30  символов - пихаем в список

Comment: судя по всему пример в вопросе неверен: _абажур торшер вышивка_ -  21 символ, _абстрактные вышивка_ - 19 , они должны быть в одной группе, потому что в сумме их длина <=40

Answer (score 1):

В лоб, как то так, без проверок и исключений:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>() {
    @"абажур ткань потолок",
    @"абажур ткань с",
    @"абажур торшер вышивка",
    @"абстрактные вышивка",
    @"абстрактные вышивки"
};

var dict = source.Select(n => new {Text = n, Count = n.Count()}).ToList();

int limit = 41;
int t_sum = dict[0].Count;
List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();

result.Add(new List<string>() { dict.First().Text });

for (int i = 1; i < dict.Count; i++)
{
    if ((dict[i].Count + t_sum) < limit)
    {
        result.Last().Add(dict[i].Text);
        t_sum += dict[i].Count;
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(new List<string>() { dict[i].Text });
        t_sum = dict[i].Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Длина строк иногда превышает 41 символ.

Comment: @Radzhab И что при этом надо сделать?

Comment: ну по идее оно не должно заноситься туда если общая длина строк увеличится более 41

Comment: @Radzhab Ну так добавьте проверку, и не заносите. Что нибудь типа  `if(dict[i].Count > limit) continue;`

Comment: ну так получится что строка вообще исчезнет

Comment: @Radzhab Куда исчезнет? У вас есть источник - массив содержащий, в том числе и, строку более 40 символов. У вас есть результат, в который, как вы сказали, эту строку мы помещать не должны, ну так ее там и нет. В любом случае, делаете вышеуказанный иф, а в его теле любые действия: выкинуть строку, урезать ее, разбить на две...